# How to search in TortoiseGit log, filtering out merge commits?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

To filter out merge commits from TortoiseGit log we can search for `!Merge`.

However, if we enter any other search keyword together with `!Merge` then the command is disregarded and the merge commits appear in the search result.

How can we search in TortoiseGit log, filtering out merge commits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the bottom of `Log Dialog`, there is a button `Walk Behaviour`. Click it and check `No merges`. Merge commits will be hidden.

Comment: How do we make this `Walk Behaviour` option as default?